# Experiencing Trouble Adding Lines to htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I'm working with an existing htaccess file that currently has Rewrite conditions but I'm trying to add additional conditions (while following a tutorial) but I'm getting a 500 Interal Server Error.

If anyone could show me what I need to do to correct this I'd be most appreciative and I thank you all once again.

Here's what my htaccess is looking like;

```
#RewriteOptions inherit
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainNameObscuredForSecurity$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^DomainNameObscuredForSecurity$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/DomainNameObscuredForSecurity" [R=301,L]

<THIS LINE IS NOT IN HTACCESS, IT'S JUST TO ILLUSTRATE THAT THE CODE BELOW IS WHAT I ADDED>

RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !=f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !=d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /somepage.xxx?=$xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

These 2 lines have wrong syntax:

```
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !=f
RewriteCond %(REQUEST_FILENAME) !=d
```

Fixed Code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /somepage.xxx?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Hi @anubhava, Thanks for pointing that out for me. If you wouldn't mind, Could you tell me what the [L,QSA] is about?

Comment: Sure Stuart. L is to mark that rule as last rule in the chain and QSA is for Query String Append. QSA is used to preserve any existing query string you might have.

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions are syntactically incorrect. You need curley braces around your variables `{}` and not an equals sign for the f and d checks:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
```

Comment: Hi @Jon Lin, Thanks for your help. Fortunately anaubhava pointed these things out but I have another question. This tutorial I am following is teaching  how to create a user profile page with a vanity URL but now my 404 isn't working. Now no matter what I type after the / (ie: www.mysite.com/texthere) takes me to that page. If a user's profile doesn't exist I need it to goto my 404 page. Is this possible with what Im doing??

Comment: Hi Guys, I think I came up with a way of preserving my 404 functionality but I don't know what I need to do to put idea into action. Please review this video. I wonder what I could put in the else block at 2:25 to preserve my 404 functionality. If anyone could help with this, I'd be most appreciative and I thank you guys once again. Here's the video. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=linTC4sr9h4